# How do I Group Picture Box click events into one?

Tags: c#, picturebox, mouseclick-event

```
private void p01_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (p01.Image == pmiss.Image)
        {
            score++;
            makeMoleVisable(1, phit);
        }
        else
        {
            score--;
            molesmissed++;
        }
    }
    private void p02_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (p02.Visible)
        {
            if (p02.Image == pmiss.Image)
            {
                score++;
                p02.Image = phit.Image;
            }
            else
            {
                score--;
                molesmissed++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hello I Have 36 of these picturebox click events. I want to use just one click event for all 36 picture boxes. Additionally all click events do the same thing, the code is just slightly different on the first one. Thnaks

Comment: Sorry it won't let me login for some reason so I'll post my comment like this. The only trouble is the (1, phit). This only lets me change the first image. How do i let the makemoleVisible know which picurebox with a mole in change to the image to phit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to the events property of each picture and set to `p02_Click` or use your own custom name.

If you have all the picture boxes in one panel, you could try:

```
foreach (Control p in mypanel.ControlCollection)
{
    p = p as PictureBox;
    p.Click += (p01_Click);
}
```

You can also test to see if it's pictureBox1 by setting a `Tag` property for `p01` and checking that property in code.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-use the eventhandler method for each group picture box. The sender argument of the method will contain the object that fired the event.

Comment: Hello I think I'm on the right track with this I just don't quite understand what you mean; so far I have this:

Comment: private void pBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox temp = (PictureBox)sender;
            if (temp.Image == pmiss.Image)
            {
                score++;
                makeMoleVisable(1, phit);
            }
            else
            {
                score--;
                molesmissed++;
            }
        }

Comment: That looks good. Does it work? Not sure if the temp.Image == pmiss.Image gives the correct result.